# Parsing ID3v2 tags with PHP only

Tags: php, tags, mp3, id3

I have pasted my PHP code for getting the ID3 tags of all MP3 files from a directory below. Everything is working fine but a lot of MP3s get their titles or albums chopped up by exactly one letter at the end, or at the begning, and sometimes both! Also some characters like `(` or `/` appear sometimes in the titles, artists or album titles. For example:

> +Skybourne (Feat. Big K.R.I.T. & Smoke DZA)
>
> !The Hangover (Feat. Mikey Rocks)
>
> *The Day (Feat. Mos Def & Jay Electronica)

My code:

```
 // set error reporting level
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.0', '>=') == 1)
  error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
else
  error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);


// gathering all mp3 files in 'mp3' folder into array
$sDir = 'music/Pilot Talk/';
$aFiles = array();
$rDir = opendir($sDir);
if ($rDir) {
    while ($sFile = readdir($rDir)) {
        if ($sFile == '.' or $sFile == '..' or !is_file($sDir . $sFile))
            continue;

        $aPathInfo = pathinfo($sFile);
        $sExt = strtolower($aPathInfo['extension']);
        if ($sExt == 'mp3') {
            $aFiles[] = $sDir . $sFile;
        }
    }
    closedir( $rDir );
}

// new object of our ID3TagsReader class
$oReader = new ID3TagsReader();

// passing through located files ..
$sList = $sList2 = '';
foreach ($aFiles as $sSingleFile) {
    $aTags = $oReader->getTagsInfo($sSingleFile); // obtaining ID3 tags info
    $sList .= '<tr><td>'.$aTags['Title'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['Author'].'</td></tr>';
                    
    $author[] .= $aTags['Author'];
    $album[] .= $aTags['Album'];
    $title[] .= $aTags['Title'];
                   
 
    $sList2 .= '<tr><td>'.$aTags['Title'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['Encoded'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['Copyright'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$aTags['Publisher'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['OriginalArtist'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['URL'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$aTags['Comments'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['Composer'].'</td></tr>'; 
}

// main output
echo strtr(file_get_contents('main_page.html'), array('__list__' => $sList, '__list2__' => $sList2));   



// class ID3TagsReader
class ID3TagsReader {

    // variables
    var $aTV23 = array( // array of possible sys tags (for last version of ID3)
        'TIT2',
        'TALB',
        'TPE1',
        'TPE2',
        'TRCK',
        'TYER',
        'TLEN',
        'USLT',
        'TPOS',
        'TCON',
        'TENC',
        'TCOP',
        'TPUB',
        'TOPE',
        'WXXX',
        'COMM',
        'TCOM'
    );
    var $aTV23t = array( // array of titles for sys tags
        'Title',
        'Album',
        'Author',
        'AlbumAuthor',
        'Track',
        'Year',
        'Length',
        'Lyric',
        'Desc',
        'Genre',
        'Encoded',
        'Copyright',
        'Publisher',
        'OriginalArtist',
        'URL',
        'Comments',
        'Composer'
    );
    var $aTV22 = array( // array of possible sys tags (for old version of ID3)
        'TT2',
        'TAL',
        'TP1',
        'TRK',
        'TYE',
        'TLE',
        'ULT'
    );
    var $aTV22t = array( // array of titles for sys tags
        'Title',
        'Album',
        'Author',
        'Track',
        'Year',
        'Length',
        'Lyric'
    );

    // constructor
    function ID3TagsReader() {}

    // functions
    function getTagsInfo($sFilepath) {
        // read source file
        $iFSize = filesize($sFilepath);
        $vFD = fopen($sFilepath,'r');
        $sSrc = fread($vFD,$iFSize);
        fclose($vFD);

        // obtain base info
        if (substr($sSrc,0,3) == 'ID3') {
            $aInfo['FileName'] = $sFilepath;
            $aInfo['Version'] = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($sSrc,3,1))).'.'.hexdec(bin2hex(substr($sSrc,4,1)));
        }

        // passing through possible tags of idv2 (v3 and v4)
        if ($aInfo['Version'] == '4.0' || $aInfo['Version'] == '3.0') {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->aTV23); $i++) {
                if (strpos($sSrc, $this->aTV23[$i].chr(0)) != FALSE) {

                    $s = '';
                    $iPos = strpos($sSrc, $this->aTV23[$i].chr(0));
                    $iLen = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($sSrc,($iPos + 5),3)));

                    $data = substr($sSrc, $iPos, 10 + $iLen);
                    for ($a = 0; $a < strlen($data); $a++) {
                        $char = substr($data, $a, 1);
                        if ($char >= ' ' && $char <= '~')
                            $s .= $char;
                    }
                    if (substr($s, 0, 4) == $this->aTV23[$i]) {
                        $iSL = 4;
                        if ($this->aTV23[$i] == 'USLT') {
                            $iSL = 7;
                        } elseif ($this->aTV23[$i] == 'TALB') {
                            $iSL = 5;
                        } elseif ($this->aTV23[$i] == 'TENC') {
                            $iSL = 6;
                        }
                        $aInfo[$this->aTV23t[$i]] = substr($s, $iSL);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // passing through possible tags of idv2 (v2)
        if($aInfo['Version'] == '2.0') {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->aTV22); $i++) {
                if (strpos($sSrc, $this->aTV22[$i].chr(0)) != FALSE) {

                    $s = '';
                    $iPos = strpos($sSrc, $this->aTV22[$i].chr(0));
                    $iLen = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($sSrc,($iPos + 3),3)));

                    $data = substr($sSrc, $iPos, 6 + $iLen);
                    for ($a = 0; $a < strlen($data); $a++) {
                        $char = substr($data, $a, 1);
                        if ($char >= ' ' && $char <= '~')
                            $s .= $char;
                    }

                    if (substr($s, 0, 3) == $this->aTV22[$i]) {
                        $iSL = 3;
                        if ($this->aTV22[$i] == 'ULT') {
                            $iSL = 6;
                        }
                        $aInfo[$this->aTV22t[$i]] = substr($s, $iSL);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $aInfo;
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: If you weren't so far along, I would suggest not doing this yourself.  I would `exec()` out to FFmpeg and let it read all the tags for you.  Then, you can support other types than just ID3v2.